# Spring boot cannot connect to other nodes of Redis-cluster when one node is down

Tags: spring-boot, redis, rate-limiting, redis-cluster

I want to build a Rate-limiter API using Redis-cluster. I made a Redis-cluster having 3 nodes running on localhost 7000, 7001 and 7002 port. The configuration of node 7000 is:

```
port 7000
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes-7000.conf
cluster-node-timeout 5000
appendonly yes
```

The other two nodes are similarly configured on port 7001 and 7002 respectively. Then I built the cluster using the command:
`redis-cli --cluster create 127.0.0.1:7000 127.0.0.1:7001 127.0.0.1:7002`
The cluster status is shown "OK" in all the 3 clusters.

In my spring-boot project, I added the configuration in my application.properties file as below:
`spring.data.redis.cluster.nodes=127.0.0.1:7000, 127.0.0.1:7001, 127.0.0.1:7002`

When all the nodes of the cluster is running, the rate-limiter works fine. But as soon as I intentionally terminate one of the nodes, let's say node 7002, it continuously gives the following error in the console:

```
Reconnecting, last destination was /127.0.0.1:7002
Cannot reconnect to [127.0.0.1/<unresolved>:7002]: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:7002
```

But the expected behavior is that the other two nodes will serve the purpose.
Please tell me if I am missing any configuration or I am having any misconception!

Comment: I believe a Redis cluster has a hard requirement of at least 3 nodes. Try bumping it up to 4 and see if the same problem happens.

Comment: I tried even with more nodes, still facing the same problem.

Comment: In that case it is probably a configuration option with the specific redis library that you're using. I would explore all configuration options in the documentation.

Comment: Additional information - I tried using 6 nodes where 3 nodes were master and 3 nodes were replicas. When the master node is down, everything is fine. But when any replica node is down, it gives the same error.